# OCaml concat stringlist using List.fold_left

Tags: ocaml

I'm getting a couple errors with the base and the f and l functions, what am I wrong wrong?

Examples of what the function is supposed to do is.

```
# sepConcat ", " ["foo";"bar";"baz"];;
- : string = "foo, bar, baz"

# sepConcat "---" [];;
- : string = ""

# sepConcat "" ["a";"b";"c";"d";"e"];;
- : string = "abcde"

# sepConcat "X" ["hello"];;
- : string = "hello"
```

The teacher gave me this code which I'm supposed to fill into.

```
let rec sepConcat sep s1 = match s1 with
  |[] -> ""
  |h::t -> 
        let f a x = failwith "to be implemented" in
    let base = failwith "to be implemented" in
    let l = failwith "to be implemented" in
        List.fold_left f base l
```

I have so far

```
let rec sepConcat sep s1 = match s1 with
  |[] -> ""
  |h::t -> 
        let f a x = a^sep^x in
    let base = 0 in
    let l = sepConcat sep t in
        List.fold_left f base l
```

Comment: I'm getting compilation errors for the base, I tried "", 0, and blank space but nothing seemed to fix it.

Comment: PSA: won't have stackoverflow at hand during the exams :)

Answer (score 2):

The error you get with your code is the following, pointing at `base` in your code:

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
       string
```

What does it mean? What is the problem? How do you fix it?

Another problem is your recursive call of `sepConcat`. Are you using `fold_left` or are you writing a recursive function? If you're doing one of these things, you don't need to do the other.

Comment: I have to follow the skeleton so I need to recursive sepConcat and call List.fold_left and I'm not sure about the base case thing since there is already |[] -> so what am i supposed to put into the base case?

Comment: The skeleton does not have a recursive call on `sepConcat`, you added it.

Comment: Indeed, there's no need to make the function sepConcat recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation using `fold_left` and an optional argument:

```
let concat ?(sep="") l =
  List.fold_left (fun acc e -> acc^sep^e) (List.hd l) (List.tl l);;
val concat : ?sep:bytes -> bytes list -> bytes = <fun>
```

And here is another implementation using a *tail recursive* function:

```
let concat ?(sep="") l =
  let rec loop acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | h::t -> loop (acc^sep^h) t
  in
  loop (List.hd l) (List.tl l);;
val concat : ?sep:bytes -> bytes list -> bytes = <fun>
```

Both behave exactly the same way:

```
concat ~sep:(" ") ["hello"; "world"];;
- : bytes = "hello world"
```